# MSSQL CLRProcedures and CLR Security Error (SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2017 to setup one of the programs that we are using.
The whole thing is working fine with MSSQL 2008 r2 but it doesn't work on 2017.

Our server information:

[image]

The software that we have has its own set of SQL queries that we cannot change, we just input the server information and it connects and sets up the database.

When it does that it gives me the following error:

```
 10342 Assembly 'CLRProcedures' cannot be loaded because this edition of SQL Server only supports SAFE assemblies.
```

and the SQL query is:

```
--Assembly clrprocedures, version=2019.2.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=2e56e3245276317a, processorarchitecture=msil
CREATE ASSEMBLY [CLRProcedures]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b800000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd21546869732070726f6772616d2063616e6e6f742062652072756e20696e20444f53206d6f64652e0d0d0a24000000000[BUNCH OF NUMBERS HERE...]

WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE

Log:
--script on: Data Source=167.71.149.66;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=SA;
GO
DROP DATABASE [Slabsmith3]
GO
--script on: Data Source=167.71.149.66;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=SA;
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Slabsmith3]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Slabsmith3] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO
SP_CONFIGURE 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
USE [Slabsmith3]
GO
--script on: Data Source=167.71.149.66;Initial Catalog=Slabsmith3;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=SA;
GO
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable
GO
CREATE USER [BackgroundTaskAcknowledger] WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE USER [ExtendedPropertyGetter] WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE USER [ExtendedPropertySetter] WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE USER [RoleProbe] WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role InventoryLock'
GO
CREATE ROLE [InventoryLock]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSBasicUser'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSBasicUser]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSInventoryManager'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSInventoryManager]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSJobCreator'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSJobCreator]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSJobViewer'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSJobViewer]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSPowerUser'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSPowerUser]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSSlabCreator'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSSlabCreator]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSSlabDeleter'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSSlabDeleter]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating role SSSlabViewer'
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSSlabViewer]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering members of role SSJobCreator'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SSJobCreator', N'SSPowerUser'
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering members of role SSSlabCreator'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SSSlabCreator', N'SSPowerUser'
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating schemas'
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [API]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Actions]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Attachments]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Audit]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Importer]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Inventory]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [NWD]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [SSAdmin]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [SSSlabBrowser]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Utilities]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Creating CLR assemblies'
GO
--Assembly clrprocedures, version=2019.2.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=2e56e3245276317a, processorarchitecture=msil
CREATE ASSEMBLY [CLRProcedures]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b800000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd21546869732070726f6772616d2063616e6e6f742062652072756e20696e20444f53206d6f64652e0d0d0a240000[BUNCH OF NUMBERS CONTINUING HERE..]

WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE
GO
```

I used the sql query below to disable CLR Security but it didn't work.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: If you read the error message and note that you have this line `WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE`  I believe the problem is clear.  You are asking for a permission it won't give you.

Comment: @Hogan how can I disable that security feature? or allow it to get permission externally?

Comment: You can't.  Take out `WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE` from your scripts

Comment: @Hogan I did that and ran the script again and I got the following error: Msg 6265, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because type "NWDSystem.RegistryHelper" in safe assembly "CLRProcedures" has a pinvokeimpl method. P/Invoke is not allowed in safe assemblies.

Comment: So go talk to the people / organization responsible for this "software" and seek their guidance and support. I'll point you to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-strict-security?view=sql-server-2017) but this might be over your head - and it is highly discouraged. Ultimately this is off-topic for SO and belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).

Comment: @dba I just e-mailed them again.

Comment: Have you tried to create the assembly under SA account?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed the game started with SQL Server 2017.

You should create SNK file by using SDK util SN.EXE. Then execute the following T-SQL script. 
The script creates an asymmetric key and corresponding login.

```
--Only for SQL SERVER 2017+
IF SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') >= '14'
   AND SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS NVARCHAR(10)), 1, 1) != '9'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);
        DECLARE @password NVARCHAR(128);
        DECLARE @tsqlToEval AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @path = N'C:\TMP\akCLRProcedures.snk';
        SET @password = N'Se1Tal0k';
        SET @tsqlToEval = N'USE MASTER;' + CHAR(13) + 'CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [akCLRProcedures]' + CHAR(13) + 'FROM FILE = ''' + @path + '''
                    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @password + '''';

        --PRINT @tsqlToEval

        IF
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM master.sys.asymmetric_keys
            WHERE name LIKE 'akCLRProcedures%'
        ) = 0
            BEGIN
                EXEC sp_executesql 
                     @tsqlToEval;
        END;
        IF NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT loginname
            FROM master.dbo.syslogins
            WHERE name = 'loginakCLRProcedures'
        )
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @sqlStatement AS NVARCHAR(1000);
                SELECT @SqlStatement = 'CREATE LOGIN [loginakCLRProcedures] FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY akCLRProcedures';
                EXEC sp_executesql 
                     @SqlStatement;
                EXEC sp_executesql 
                     N'USE MASTER;
                      GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [loginakCLRProcedures];';
        END;
END;
```

----update 26.9.2019.

### The following snippet create an asymmetric key using Password

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY akCLRProcedures
    WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 
        /* 
            Other Algorithms Supported as follows

            RSA_512
            RSA_1024
            AES_256
        */
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'UseAReallyStrongPasswordHere'
```

Comment: My setup is on Linux (Ubuntu), we probably don't have SN.exe, what is SNK, SDK util? I can try to locate it.

Comment: I updated the answer. See how to create an asymmetric key by pure T-SQL.